# What does "world-class tendered" mean?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm confused about the structure of this sentence when I read this text:

> And that's why I start the businesses that I start, that's usually
>   consumer brands, that have embedded in them the very best of my
>   African culture. ***And what I do is it's all packaged, 21st century,
>   world-class tendered***, and I bring that to one of the most
>   sophisticated markets in the world, which is the US

.

> And what I do is it's all packaged, 21st century, world-class tendered

What kind of word is "world-class tendered"? As what I saw in dictionary, "world-class" is an adjective, but how about "tendered" here? is it a participle? This confusion makes me misunderstand the meaning of this sentence. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Syntactically, your cited text is all over the place - it's an example of what happens in off-the-cuff ***speech***, when people aren't necessarily too bothered about precise grammar. But despite the name, analysing it for "parts of speech" is probably a fool's errand.

Comment: ...so far as I can see, the sequence [***world-class tendered***](https://www.google.nl/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB807GB807&ei=JPu4W-X6KND8kwWnzoqIAw&q=%22world-class+tendered%22&oq=%22world-class+tendered%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9321.11568.0.12242.2.2.0.0.0.0.111.206.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.b3fLkusmJag) has only been indexed 7 times by Google, and all hits except this specific cited (invalid, imho) example are for ***world-class tendered procurement strategies*** - which does seem syntactically credible to me.

Comment: You're confused about the structure? I'm confused about the content and meaning. I presume the writer knows what he (or she) is trying to say but  he (or she) has not expressed it in normal, clear, colloquial English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it up into sections, then:

> And what I do is it's all packaged, 21st century, world-class
>   tendered.

"And what I do is ..." stands for "***And here is what I do:***" or "***And what I do is as follows:***"

"It's all packaged" is really "***Everything*** [i.e. all my merchandise] ***is packaged."***

"21st century" means "***Truly up-to-date***," "***very modern***," "***state-of-the-art.***"

"world-class tendered": "***Presented in a manner comparable to that of the best companies in the entire world***."

I hope this helps.